# Is $x^n$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I know that it's not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ but on $[0,a]$ with $a < 1$. Does that mean it converges uniformly on $[0,1)$?

Comment: No - hence the use of $a$

Comment: Hint: If $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on a set $E,$ then $\sup_E |f_n| \to 0.$

Comment: It is not uniformly convergent in $[0,1)$. You can try to prove it yourself: Try to prove that for all $M\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $x\in[0,1)$ such that $x^M>1/2$ (Hint: Bernoulli inequality). Then you proved that "there exists $\epsilon>0$ (namely $\epsilon=1/2$) such that for all $M\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\geq M$ (namely $n=M$) and there exists $x\in[0,1)$ with $|x^n-0|>\epsilon$". This is the negation of uniform convergence.

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer?  If it could be real and less than $1$ then the problem is different.

Answer (score 4):

A sequence uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$ will also be uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ because only one point is being added. Assuming of course that it does converge at $1$.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $f_n(x):=x^n$ converges pointwise to $f(x):=0$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. But plugging $x=1-\frac1n$ into $f_n$, we can certainly say
$$
\textstyle \sup_x|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge(1-\frac1n)^n\tag1
$$
The RHS of (1) tends to a nonzero limit (namely $1/e$), so the LHS does not converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The reason uniform convergence fails on $[0,1]$ is because the convergence $x^n \to 0$ occurs at later and later $n$ when $x$ is picked closer and closer to $1$. No matter how big you fix an $N$ there will still be $x$'s (necessarily) close to $1$ such that $x^n$ is still bigger than $1/2$, say.

Exclusion of $x=1$ will not change this. In other words, the problem is not $1$ but a neighborhood of it. This is why cutting away a $\delta$ neighborhood of $1$ makes things work.